# Rails 4.2 + Postgres not equals != <> on INNER JOIN on polymorphic association

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to return all Posts that belong to an Hnode and that have not been hidden by the user. I have a **'hides'** table that allows a user to hide a post. Hide is a polymorphic association (hideable) because I also have comments that can be hidden. When a user hides a Post, a Hide record is created with the following data:

```
Hide:
  id: #{some_id} 
  hideable_type: 'Post'
  hideable_id: #{some_post_id}
  user_id: #{some_user_id}
```

**I want to fetch Posts that have not been hidden by the user.** (See below for models and associations.)

In short, when I try to remove all posts which have been hidden by the current user, signified by the many-to-many association table "hides" I get results that should be hidden:

```
posts = Post.where(hnode_id: params[:hnode_id])
            .joins("LEFT JOIN hides ON hides.hideable_type = 'Post' AND hides.hideable_id = posts.id AND hides.user_id != #{current_user.id}")
```

**User Load (0.3ms)**  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["uid", "email@fake-email.com"]]

**Post Load (0.7ms)**  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" LEFT JOIN hides ON hides.hideable_type = 'Post' AND hides.hideable_id = posts.id AND hides.user_id != 1 WHERE "posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "posts"."hnode_id" = $1  ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0  [["hnode_id", 12]]

My data is correct - meaning that I do have Hide records with the current user's id in the user_id column.

Here are my models with the appropriate associations:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hides, as: :hideable
  ...
end

#app/models/hnode.rb
class Hnode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  ...
end

# app/models/hide.rb
class Hide < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hnode
  belongs_to :hideable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hides
  has_many :posts
  ...
end
```

What is the right way to exclude posts from query results based on a many-to-many relationship association such as hides (based on hides.user_id)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `AND (hides.user_id != 1)` doesn't belong in the WHERE clause. It effectively turns your LEFT JOIN into a plain JOIN. (I don't know it this whas your intention; the question is not very clear.)

Comment: Hi wildplasser, I clarified the question and simplified the setup. I believe you are correct that I have the (hides.user_id != 1) in the wrong place - meaning it should be in the JOINS call. I will see what I can come up with. Thanks.